# Except for baudhyana dharma sutras which other dharma sastras talk about loss of caste due to sea voyage?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras, smriti

> Baudhayana Dharma-sutra, composed about 2,000 years ago, maybe
>   earlier, lists this "Samudrolanghana" or "Sagarollanghana" as the
>   first of many reasons for loss of castes (II.1.2.2).

Are there other dharma sutras prohibiting sea voyages?

Comment: What about flight crossing

Comment: It's only about travelling through seas I think.. and there is a reason for it.. @RakeshJoshi

Comment: @Rickross Because there were no aeroplane that time thats why ?

Comment: It has something to do with water and the Gayatri mantra. I am not sure about how the intsructions would have been if there were aeroplanes in those days. @RakeshJoshi Probably it would have been different because travelling by air hardly takes 1/2 days.. but in case of travelling   on ships it was a matter of months.

Answer (score 9):

The Manu Smriti also mentions undertaking sea voyage as a prohibited act. One becomes fallen/degraded by doing so.

For example, in the list of all the persons who are not considered fit to be invited in a Deva/Pitru related sacrifice, one who has undertaken a sea voyage is there.

> 3.157. He who forsakes his mother, his father, or a teacher without a (sufficient) reason, he who has contracted an alliance with outcasts
>   either through the Veda or through a marriage,
>
> 3.158. An incendiary, a prisoner, he who eats the food given by the son of an adulteress, a seller of Soma, he
>   **who undertakes voyages by sea**, a bard, an oil-man, a suborner to perjury,
>
> ...........................
>
> 3.166. A shepherd, a keeper of buffaloes, the husband of a remarried woman, and a carrier of dead bodies, **(all these) must be carefully
>   avoided.**

Similar prohibition is held by the Usana Smriti (which is one of the 18 Smritis) as well. Following are the verses from the 4th Chapter of the Text:

> One, who injures a friend ; one, who is deceitful ; one, who daily
>   beats women ; one, who renounces his parents and preceptor ; as well
>   as one, who renounces his wife; (32) One, who has no issue ; one, who
>   gives false evidence ; one, who cooks food ; one, who lives by
>   treating diseases ; **one who goes to sea** ; one, who is ungrateful ;
>   one, who breaks a high way ; and one, who breaks an agreement ; (33)
>   One, who is given to the vilification of the Vedas; one, who is given
>   to speaking against the Deities ; one, who is given to speaking ill of
>   the twice-born ; **[all these] should be avoided in all rites
>   appertaining to a S'raddha.**