# Hanuman and Sagarollanghana

Tags: hanuman, sin, smriti

I read in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28675/except-for-baudhyana-dharma-sutras-which-other-dharma-sastras-talk-about-loss-of) that Sagarollanghana is prohibited and leads to a loss of caste. Now Sagarollanghana literally means 'leaping over the Saagara'. It appears from the answer that the Manusmriti also corroborates this though I don't know the exact Sanskrit term used there.

Was there any sin attached to Hanuman in this case? If there was, was there anything in particular that Hanuman did to recover from this possible sin / loss of caste? I am looking for something in scripture if possible. (I don't doubt the greatness of Hanuman, only interested in knowing if there was something mentioned about this)

Comment: But is it applicable to gods also? I think he didn't travel by boat but once went by flying. He was already blessed by all gods when young. So i dont think such things are applicable to him. There are also stories of people going out of earth itself..what about them ?

Comment: The term specifically means leaping over the sea/ocean and does not involve boats, so am interested in knowing more. I agree that it may not be applicable. I just want to know if there is some sort of analysis of this done.

Comment: its better not to use such words. I mean assuming that he already incured sin.

Comment: I agree and hence mentioned in the title 'if there was any'. I'll also put it in the body of the question. If you have any better ways of mentioning it, please feel free to edit.

Comment: From [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199938.html), the Sanskrit word is samudrayāyī (sea-voyager). Related: [What are the varnas (castes) of Lord Hanuman and Jambavan?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19180/2995)

Comment: Thanks @sv. for the verse. It appears from that context that the term means someone who _habitually/professionally_ goes out to sea rather than someone who does it once / rarely.

Comment: @user1952500 Rules of Humans are not applicable to gods.  It's  mentioned in Matsya Purana . Besides Hanuman even crossed the earth  before , at childhood.

Comment: How much time Hanuman took to cross the sea? I think this info is crucial here.

Comment: Related [Clarification on loosing caste due to Samudrolanghana (sea voyage)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23954/clarification-on-loosing-caste-due-to-samudrolanghana-sea-voyage)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think we are missing to see the real reason behind the prohibition here.

In ancient times, crossing the ocean means travelling on the ship for months. But according to Manu Smriti and other similar texts, one should not recite Vedas on a ship.

> Manu Smriti 4.120. **Let him not recite the Veda** on horseback, nor
>   on a tree, nor on an elephant, nor **in a boat (or ship)**, nor on a
>   donkey, nor on camel, nor standing on barren ground, nor riding in a
>   carriage,

So, while travelling on a ship one can not recite the Gayatri Mantra (which is a Vedic Mantra and which is also known as the mother of the Vedas). But without reciting the Gayatri one can not perform the Sandhya. So, basically one who is crossing the sea will not be able to perform Sandhya for months.

Now,  Sandhya is a Nitya Karma for the Dvijas which he should be performing daily without fail. By failing to do so for months one will lose caste, becomes degraded as said in the verse given below:

> Manu Smriti 2.103. **But he who does not (worship) standing in the
>   morning, nor sitting in the evening, shall be excluded, just like a
>   Sudra,** from all the duties and rights of an Aryan

But, for someone like Hanuman, who is/was endowed with super natural powers, crossing the sea wouldn't  be a matter of even minutes. And, furthermore, he won't be boarding a ship, he will simply fly across the ocean.

So, the prohibition does not really apply to super natural beings like Hanuman.

Answer (score 2):

Sundara Kanda:

> प्लवमानं तु तं दृष्ट्वा प्लवङ्गं त्वरितं तदा | 
>  ववर्षुः
>   पुष्पवर्षणि देवगन्धर्वदानवाः || ५-१-८३
>
> Then, on seeing Hanuman flying quickly in the sky, Devas, Gandharvas
>   and Danavas showered flowers on him.
>
> तताप न हि तं सूर्यः प्लवन्तं वानरोत्तमम् |
>  सिषेवे च तदा वायू
>   रामकार्याद्थसिद्धये || ५-१-८४
>
> Then, the Sun did not scorch Hanuman, the best among Vanaras, **who
>   was flying for Rama's welfare.** The wind god Vayu also served him
>   with a delightful breeze.
>
> ऋषयस्तुष्टुवुश्चैव प्लवमानं विहायसा |
>  जगुश्च देवगन्धर्वाः
>   प्रशंसन्तो महौजसम् || ५-१-८५
>
> Sages praised the great resplendent Hanuman flying in the sky. Devas
>   and Gandharvas also sang in His praise.
>
> नागाश्च तुष्टुवुर्यक्षा रक्षांसि विबुधाः खगाः || ५-१-८६
>  प्रेक्ष्य
>   सर्वे कपिवरं सहसा विगतक्लमम् |
>
> Immediately on seeing the best among monkeys, Hanuman, flying without
>   any effort, Nagas, Yakshas, Rakshasas, Devas and birds all praised
>   Him.
>
> ...
>  ...
>  ...
>
> तद्द्वितीयं हनुमतो दृष्ट्वा कर्म सुदुष्करम् |
>  प्रश्शंसुः सुराः
>   सर्वे सिद्धाश्च परमर्षयः || १-५-१३७
>
> Seeing Hanuman perform that very difficult second task (first one being
>   the flight over ocean), all Devas, Siddhas and great sages praised
>   Him.
>
> ...
>  ...
>  ...
>
> रामस्यैष हितायैव याति दाशरथेर्हरिः |
>  सत्क्रियां कुर्वता तस्य
>   तोषितोऽस्मि दृढं त्वया || ५-१-१४२
>
> This Vanara Hanuman is going for the benefit of Sri Rama, the son of
>   Dasaratha. I am very happy with you who is doing respect to Him.
>   (Indra to Mainak parvat).

When every celestial being, including Indra and the rishis were so happy with Hanuman, I don't think he incurred any sin.

Comment: I am not sure about this line of reasoning. As a counter-example, all gods praised Rama for having killed Ravana, but still he did a parihara for the brahma-hatya dosha.

Comment: I speculate that Ram did such because he himself felt guilty. In fact when he was a god, the supreme God in fact, I don't think such rules hold for beings who are originally not humans.