# Why crossing seas does not yield fruit?

Tags: ramayana, rama

I read that act done after crossing the seas would yield no fruit.

I also heard many Gurus in India do not travel abroad. 
Why is this restriction?

Rama crossed the ocean but you may say it's through bridge. But Ravana, crossed it to kidnap Sita in Vimana. He is one of the greatest Brahmin with all the knowledge to know what is good. Rama also his return to Ayodhya came in Vimana, flying over the ocean.

Comment: You can see [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28897/4732) to understand the reasons behind the prohibition. Also you need to understand that at present we hardly use ships to go to another country so travel abroad does not take that much time as it used to take earlier.

Comment: You are right. Crossing seas have nothing to do with yielding fruits. These wierd ideas are in Smritis that are now completely obsolete and are not followed by Hindus.

Comment: I'm answering this from my viewpoint, in the olden days, Brahmins were not supposed to cross seas because it may be that our knowledge might get polluted with foreign thoughts, Bharat-varsha was/is a land of Immense Knowledge while the other Countries were not that rich with knowledge, so, to preserve the knowledge and protect it from foreign pollutants, people refrained from crossing seas. Regarding Dashananda, modern philosophers state that Ravana was born somewhere in the Northern region and by taking this 'theory', he did not cross seas. And this is my view, I might be wrong.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay, if you restrict your definition of 'yielding fruits' to those of worldly actions, you are correct. But for vedic rituals, Bharat is karma bhumi.Other countries are full of rajas/tamasic people. Such people exist in India too but ratio/concentration is much lower. The land, water etc. are all non-conducive for vedic karma. Calling these ideas as weird, and dismissing them just because they are in 'Smritis' - actually makes your pov the weird one. "not followed by Hindus" - just because Swami Vivekananda didn't, doesn't mean other Hindus don't.

Comment: hello learned scholars, i am follower of mahan sankaracharya. I am wondering if this could also be because of climatic reasons where we might not be able to perform sandhyavandanam?
And also, we are doing sankalpam with respect to geographic landmarks mountains and rivers in India?
Please enlighten me with your views.